A sequence can only converge in a metric space if the succesive gap between sequence element get smaller (Speculative result)
Consider a metric space $(M,d)$ and a sequence in it $\{a_i\}_{i \in \mathbb{N}}$ , I want to show that it can not converge if there exists some $N$, such that for $i > N$, $$d(a_{i+2},a_{i+1}) \geq d( a_{i+1}, a_i )$$
Intuitively, the idea of what I want to show is that you can only converge if the gap between the consecutive sequence elements eventually gets smaller and smaller.
One can convince themself this claim is probably true by taking examples of sequences like $a_n=n$ or $a_n = n² + n $
For this end, I use the implication that convergent sequences are cauchy. I take the negation of cauchy statement
$$ \exists \epsilon \in \mathbb{R^+} , \forall N \in \mathbb{N}: \exists n,m \in \mathbb{N} : d(a_n,a_m) > \epsilon  \text{ and }n,m > N$$
I hope the negation is without errors. I think there is some redundancy in the statement, that is some parts can be made away , but I am not sure how to. Nonetheless it is unclear how to reduce the Cauchy definition into the fact that the sequence can not converge if the purported statement of the sequence is true.

Isn’t this true by definition of convergence in the topology induced by the metric? Except for eventually constant sequences, of course.

Can you elaborate @Pranay

Your condition implies that $d(a_{i+1},a_i) \ge d(a_{N+2},a_{N+1}) = c \ge 0$ for all $i>N$. For $c>0$, this inequality means that consecutive terms of the sequence are bounded away from each other by the constant $c$, so it cannot converge by definition. If $c=0$, then the sequence could be eventually constant, which is convergent.
